Disable SSH server on my Pi 5, should I still worry about intrusion if I have a simple password?
I have disabled SSH and uninstall the SSH server on my raspberry PI 5. I have also installed UFW with default settings. Should I still worry about intrusion if I have a simple login password?
Thanks

Do you have any internet facing services like a web server, mail server, or etc?  If the Pi is behind a NAT with an IP like 192.168.0.0-192.168.255.255 and there is no port forwarding it is not directly exposed to the internet then it should be relatively secure.  If it has any internet facing services, random bots will attempt to brute force or otherwise attack it.

Passwords are actually not stored on the system; a one-way hash of them is.  When you enter a password, it is run through a cryptographic function to produce such a hash value and if they are the same, the login succeeds.  However, you cannot use the hash itself, nor can the actual password be derived from the hash (hence "one-way", which is why, if you forget the password, it must be replaced).
This is considered best practice for password authentication implementations, but it doesn't make you immune to things like rootkit  keyloggers, security bugs, etc.
WRT "simple passwords", the risk is with regard to something that can access the system without root privileges trying to switch users by guessing the password. In order to do that, it must use an executable with special features ("setuid") that can run as a privileged process and these are implemented with time delays, meaning this brute force style attack cannot be well automated -- it won't be much more effective than a person just sitting there at a login prompt.
